# Passing variables to a function

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a module with a view function named 'edit' and a function named 'handle_upload'.

I would like to pass two variable values, which are available in the edit function, to the handle_upload function, but I don't know how, since I don't call the handle_upload function in the view function, so I can't pass the values as parameters.

For clarity:

```
# my_module.py

def edit():
    dynamic variable #1
    dynamic variable #2
    render_to_response(some_site.html, locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))

def handle_upload():
    # here is where I would want to get both variables.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you want the variables to be available in two separate requests to the django server - first you want to set them when the user goes to the `edit` view, then you want to retrieve them in another view that calls `handle_upload`.

There are two options here, depending on the actual data you want to pass.

- Pass it to the template and add it as hidden fields in the edit form.

This might be the easiest way, but be careful with sensitive data. If you don't want malicious users to see (and even edit) this data, don't do this. Users can and will edit the hidden html fields if they have bad intentions. Don't rely on this information to be correct if it can compromise the safety of your server.

First I'd like to advise you to use `render` instead of `render_to_response`, as the latter is outdated and will soon be deprecated. `render` ensures you have a `RequestContext` object, and requires the first argument to be the actual `request` object:

```
render(request, 'some_site.html', locals())
```

Then in your template, inside the form:

```
<input type='hidden' name='name1' value='{{ dynamic_variable_1 }}' />
<input type='hidden' name='name2' value='{{ dynamic_variable_2 }}' />
```

Then use `request.POST.get('name1')` to get the value of `dynamic_variable_1` etc.

- Use session middleware.

This way the data will stay on the server, and will even remain to be a Python object, so this handles every kind of object (I think, not 100% sure on that).

First, ensure `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'` is in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your settings.py. It is by default if you used Django's `startapp` command.

Then, do the following in `edit`:

```
request.session['name1'] = dynamic_variable1
request.session['name2'] = dynamic_variable2
```

Then in the view that calls `handle_upload`, simply do the following and pass the variables to `handle_upload`:

```
dynamic_variable1 = request.session['name1']
dynamic_variable2 = request.session['name2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

- declare your two variables global using the `global` keyword
- have `handle_upload` take two arguments, and pass the two variables in

If you aren't calling it from `edit()`, that means you would need to return the two variables from `edit()` to the call site, and then pass them into `handle_upload()` from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for something like:

```
 dynamic variable #1
 dynamic variable #2

 def edit():
      global dynamic variable #1, dynamic variable #2
      render_to_response(… )

 def handle_upload():
       global dynamic variable #1, dynamic variable #2
      #…
```

But be carefull with global variables if you are multithreading. If you do so consider a lock ;-)